# MPMoviePlayer receiving end of HLS Video Notification too soon

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer, http-live-streaming

I'm using a NSNotification Observer to check when the end of the video is reached like this:

***ViewDidLoad***

...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(movieFinished:)
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
```

...

```
- (void)movieFinished:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSDictionary *notificationUserInfo = [note userInfo];
    NSNumber *resultValue = [notificationUserInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];
    MPMovieFinishReason reason = [resultValue intValue];
```

When I inspect the variable ***reason*** I get *MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded*

The problem I'm having is that I am receiving *MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded* before the live stream has ended.

I am testing this same HLS stream on an android device and the live stream never ends, but this iOS app video goes black.

Can someone help me find a reason why I would receive the *MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded* notification prior to the end of the stream? Are there more ways to debug this issue?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having the same problem with a video. Playback Ended is sent before the video is over.

Comment: No, sorry this was a awhile ago, but I believe we ended up using a third party video player instead so I don't think i ever found an answer.